# Android - How to override Display Color Inversion Programmatically

Tags: android

In Android,  similar to how the Font Size (set from Settings > Accessibility) can be overridden programmatically via WebSettings setTextZoom().

Can Color Inversion (set from Settings > Accessibility) be overridden programmatically?